# yellowbrick librarie isn't importing on jupyter lab

Tags: import, yellowbrick

I can't use the librarie yellowbrick on my jupyter lab. I want to specifically use the KElbowVisualizer,
but it's just impossible (and I know that it seems a simple problem but I tried everything).

I always get the same message: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yellowbrick' // as if it was not installed.

I tried to download it using pip through jupiter lab (and I also installed it on my cmd), but it sad everything was already 'satisfied' (downloaded).

I also used !pip list on my jupyter lab and there was it: yellowbrick

And just to make sure I restarted my kernel more than once, but it just doesn't work!

what should I do??

IMPORTANT: I can't use conda, only pip.

Comment: Thanks for specifying you want a `pip`-based solution. You don't say how you installed through JupyterLab; however, given you mention an exclamation point with `pip list` & since it isn't working I'm guessing you followed poor advice and are using an exclamation point with `pip install`.  The command you want to run in your running Jupyter `.ipynb` file is `%pip install yellowbrick`. Make a new cell and run that and then restart the kernel. You probably should at least refresh the browser, if not shut down all Jupyter and your browser and restart. Some of the more complex installs involving...

Comment: <contimued> controlling how things dispplay, like it looks like yellowbrick does, need more than just refreshing the kernel. The magic pip command variation was added to insure the install occurs in the environment where the kernel is running that backs the active notebook. The exclamation point doesn't do that and can lead to issues. You should be also using `%pip list` to see what is installed in the kernel that your notebook is using. See more about the modern `%pip install` ...

Comment: <continued>  command [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez). [The second paragraph here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) goes into more details about why the exclamation point may lead to issues. Even if that doesn't fix your issue here, you'll have a better experience in modern Jupyter using the magic varations of `pip` for running inside the notebook. They even work in JupyterLite and Google Colab. You can use that as a gauge...

Comment: <continued> for whether advice you find is using current best practices or outdated. If the advice has exclamation point with `pip`, then beware.

Comment: apperentaly using %pip install yellowbrick in a cell worked as intended. Thanks so much for the simple solution!

Comment: Great. Sometimes it's not apparent it will solve it because there could be something else downstream.

Answer (score 0):

The command you want to run in your running Jupyter `.ipynb` file is:

```py
%pip install yellowbrick
```

Make a new cell and run that and then restart the kernel. You probably should at least refresh the browser, if not shut down all Jupyter and your browser and restart. Some of the more complex installs involving controlling how things display, like it looks like yellowbrick does, need more than just refreshing the kernel.

The magic pip command variation was added in 2019 to insure the install occurs in the environment where the kernel is running that backs the active notebook.

The exclamation point doesn't do that and can lead to issues. You should be also using `%pip list` to see what is installed in the kernel that your notebook is using.

See more about the modern `%pip install` command [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez). [The second paragraph here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) goes into more details about why the exclamation point may lead to issues.